# Setting widget's looks inside AppWidget Configuration activity

Tags: java, android, configuration, android-appwidget

How do I show my appWidget in my appWidget Configuration Activity and let the user costumize it? (Color, Opacity, Picture, etc...)?

Couldn't find any example of how to do it... and could't think of any convinient way...

So I'll be very happy for your help...

Tried this, but it Throws exception: "The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.":

```
public class WidgetConfigure_abs2 extends Activity {

@Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    setContentView(R.layout.widget_super_layout);

    final LayoutInflater factory = getLayoutInflater();

    final View widgetView = factory.inflate(R.layout.widget_super_layout_1x1, null);

    addContentView(widgetView, null);

    .
    .
    .
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So simple, but somehow I missed it:

just added this to my configuration activity layout XML:

```
 <include
        android:id="@+id/widgetInclude"
        android:layout_width="76dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        layout="@layout/added_layout" />
```